# I'm trying to identify a tree i saw in Taormina, Sicily, Italy. Can anyone help?

Tags: botany, species-identification

What is the identity of this tree? These pictures were taken in Taormina, Sicily.

[image: unknown Sicilian Tree]

Comment: Was an obviously planted tree or did it look like a native species of the region?

Comment: It was on farmland..so I would have guessed a native species, but it seems not; Thanks to RHA for explaining that its native only to eastern Australia. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Silky oak, *Grevillea robusta*, which is btw not related to our indigenous oaks *(quercus)*.
It's native only to eastern Australia, so planted in Sicily.
https://pommepal.wordpress.com/tag/silky-oak/

Comment: This looks spot on.